# Firefox extension clipboard on headless mode not working

Tags: ubuntu, firefox-addon, clipboard

I develop a extension, which adds the option to display device data like clipboard contents etc. I noticed that

```
document.execCommand("paste");
```

returns nothing when testing it in headless mode with selenium. I have also written a test page to confirm this:

```js
function copyStringToClipboard(str) {                                                                                                                                                          
    const el = document.createElement('textarea');                                                                                                                                             
    el.value = str;                                                                                                                                                                            
    el.setAttribute('readonly', '');                                                           
    el.style = {position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px'};
    document.body.appendChild(el);                                                             
    el.select();                               
    document.execCommand('copy');                                                              
    document.body.removeChild(el);             
}                                                                                              
                                               
function getClipBoard() {                                                                      
    const el = document.createElement("div");  
    document.body.appendChild(el);                                                             
    el.contentEditable = true;                 
    el.style = {position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px'};
                                               
    const range = document.createRange();   
    range.selectNode(el);                 
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    el.focus();         
    document.execCommand("paste");
    return el.innerHTML;
}
copyStringToClipboard("test")

getClipBoard() // is empty
```

Any reasons why this could happen?

Answer (score 0):

From the doc:

> The difference between the two APIs is that document.execCommand this
> is analogous to the keyboard copy, cut, and paste actions – exchanging
> data between a webpage and clipboard – whereas navigator.clipboard
> writes and reads arbitrary data to and from the clipboard.

Are you sure that the problem is with `paste` and not `copy`?

copy:
`navigator.clipboard.writeText("test");`

And if you want to read from the clipboard use [Clipboard.readText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText#example)